# jmeter response assertion to assert more than one different patterns

Tags: jmeter, response, assertion

For example, my response as following:
{......
"messageStatus":"SUCCESS","warnings":[{"warningCode":1003,"warningMessage":"Warning when calling downstream service. service = repricing, reason = Warning(warningCode=2503, warningMessage=Sell rate 7.0000 must be within rate verification threshold."}]}
I would like use response assertion: 
1. when messageStatus:success, without warningcode, the response is success 
2. when the response contains "warningcode", the response is failure

so how do I use response assertion to achieve it? I try to use two response assertions: one is Contains: "messageStatus":"SUCCESS"; the other is Substring and checked Not: "warningCode", it seems like to achieve what I want, but I would like to use more simplify method to get it, could you you help me or give some suggestion? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following configuration:

- Pattern Matching Rules: `Contains`
- Pattern 1: `"messageStatus":"SUCCESS"`
- Pattern 2: `(?s)^((?!warningCode).)*$`

This way assertion will fail if:

1. `"messageStatus":"SUCCESS"` line is NOT FOUND

   or
2. `warningCode` line IS FOUND

[image: JMeter Assertion 2 Clauses]

In `Contains` mode [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) treats patterns as [Perl-5 Style Regular Expressions](http://jkorpela.fi/perl/regexp.a) so you have full flexibility on defining custom pass/fail criteria.

More information: [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved)